# Recursive Movie - using a structure with recursive movie sequels and printing

Tags: c

Implement a structure type named Movie. Use appropriate data types and names for the
structure’s members. Add a member to the movie structure which represents whether the movie
has a sequel, or not; this member should be a pointer to a struct Movie.
In the main function instantiate four structure variables, one for each movie listed in the table
above. For this exercises, ensure each Movie structure variable is stored on the heap. Set the
members of each structure appropriately.
Next, create a function named print_movie, which can be passed a single struct Movie
variable by reference. Declare a prototype for this function.
Use function recursion to print out a movie’s details, and its sequels, if it has any. When the Jurassic
Park structure variable reference is passed to the print_movie function the following output
must be generated:

I've been stuck on this problem for hours, this is what I've gotten and don't know where to go next.. I've gone through lecture slides and recordings and I just can't figure out what to do.

would really appreciate it if someone explains recursive and pointers, I've been covering it for a week and I still have no idea when to use a pointer and when to do what. This is just something that isn't sticking...

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

struct Movie
{
char movies_name[32];
int year;
int score;
struct Movie* sequel;
};

struct print_movie(*Jurrassic_Park);

int main(void)
{
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

struct Movie* Jurassic_Park = 0;
Jurassic_Park = malloc(sizeof(struct Movie)*4);

sprintf(Jurassic_Park[0].movies_name, "Jurassic Park");
Jurassic_Park[0].year = 1993;
Jurassic_Park[0].score = 93;
*Jurassic_Park[0].sequel= Jurassic_Park[1];

sprintf(Jurassic_Park[1].movies_name, "The Lost World: Jurassic Park");
Jurassic_Park[1].year = 1997;
Jurassic_Park[1].score = 51;
*Jurassic_Park[1].sequel = Jurassic_Park[2];

sprintf(Jurassic_Park[2].movies_name, "Jurassic Park III");
Jurassic_Park[2].year = 2001;
Jurassic_Park[2].score = 50;
*Jurassic_Park[2].sequel = Jurassic_Park[3];

sprintf(Jurassic_Park[3].movies_name, "Jurassic World");
Jurassic_Park[3].year = 2015;
Jurassic_Park[3].score = 72;
Jurassic_Park[3].sequel = NULL;

print_movie(Jurassic_Park);

return 0;

    
    struct print_movie(*Jurrassic_Park)
    {
    printf("Name: %s", Jurrassic_Park[k].movies_name);
    printf("Year of Release: %d", Jurrassic_Park[k].year);
    printf("Rotten Tomatoes: %d%%", Jurrassic_Park[k].score)
    
    }
```

I was considering using a for loop here but wasn't sure if that's how this question is meant to be printed i.e. is it meant to be called in the main multiple times for each movie or are you supposed to print it with a for loop.

Edit:
I've got the program to run but it isn't printing or showing anything.

This is my print function

```
void print_movie(struct Movie* Jurrassic_Park)
{
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{
    printf("Name: %s", Jurrassic_Park[k].movies_name);
    printf("Year of Release: %d", Jurrassic_Park[k].year);
    printf("Rotten Tomatoes: %d%%", Jurrassic_Park[k].score);
}

}
```

Comment: `sprintf(Jurassic_Park[0].movies_name, "Jurassic Park");`  --> you meant `strcpy()`?

Comment: Our lecturer interchangeably used sprintf and strycpy. I've been using sprint since then you don't need to use #include <string.h>

Comment: but then you got the syntax wrong!

Comment: Isn't it the same as strcpy(variablename.member,"text")?

Comment: that's right for strcpy...but if you don;t have any format conversion to be made, don;t use a formatted IO function.

Comment: The synthax looks ok to me.

Comment: `int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...)`

Comment: Using `sprintf` instead of `strcpy` because then you don't need to include string.h is a very poor excuse. IMO your lecturer should not teach C.

Comment: Not my lecturer's reasoning, mine lol. He interchangeably used it and I thought it would be easier to use since its less coding and I have trouble with time during tests.

Comment: BTW: you should indent your code properly, it's for your own good. I'm sure your lecturer told you about indentation, if not....

Comment: I space it better on visual studio, it doesn't come across well on here.

Comment: OK, then just don't use sprintf when you can use strcpy